# What does the argmax of the expectation of the log likelihood mean?

Tags: machine-learning, math, probability, notation, expectation

What does the following equation mean? What does each part of the formula represent or mean?

$$\theta^* = \underset {\theta}{\arg \max} \Bbb E_{x \sim p_{data}} \log {p_{model}(x|\theta) }$$

Comment: Hi Arash. This is a legitimate question. However, next time, please, provide some context, that is, describe where you saw this formula.

Answer (score 3):

This equation and more information of it can be found in [Expectation Maximization Wikipedia site](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expectation%E2%80%93maximization_algorithm#Applications) and the explanation there was as follows (formula there in two parts):

[image]

Some more explanation from same page:

> In statistics, an expectation–maximization (EM) algorithm is an iterative method to find maximum likelihood or maximum a posteriori (MAP) estimates of parameters in statistical models, where the model depends on unobserved latent variables. The EM iteration alternates between performing an expectation (E) step, which creates a function for the expectation of the log-likelihood evaluated using the current estimate for the parameters, and a maximization (M) step, which computes parameters maximizing the expected log-likelihood found on the E step. These parameter-estimates are then used to determine the distribution of the latent variables in the next E step.

Mathematically, `E` in your equation stands for Expectation Value,  `x|theta` is conditional probability and `x~data` and `model` are sub-titles of source of probability in either case. The `arg max theta` is argument `theta` that maximizes the equation.